# How to configure a 360 degree view to Product images?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, product-view, image-preview

I have to create a store with Products having 180 as well as 360 Degree View.
I had gone through many extensions like magic 360 and many more but Cant find anything relevant.

I wish to use the free and effective extension for my purpose.
Even if you are able to provide some paid solutions or magento tweeks you are welcome.

Also can you let me know about the how to change the product image if one of the attribute is changed in configurable product.(Except the color swatches because it is built in feature of magento.)

Comment: Try this module  https://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/modules/magento/

Comment: Also https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/arqspin-360-product-photography-1.html

Comment: You can purchase this extension [360 product views](https://www.mageants.com/360-product-images-extension-for-magento-2.html) With this extension you can add a 360-degree product image, Control animation effects, and speed

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a chance to try this Magento extension as it allows both 180° and 360 product views?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webrotate-360-product-viewer-with-prettyphoto-lightbox-image-gallery.html

PS: it doesn't support multiple 360s for configurable product options yet...

Comment: is there any option available for 360 degree view of product view? Also let me know the free and paid options available for the same.

Comment: Yes, the option for 360 degree view is available. The Overview tab on the linked page has more details and a demo link. The module is free but you can upgrade to PRO version of the core product viewer which has some extras as per the Overview tab links.